# What support exists for uri-templates?

Tags: html, standards, uritemplate

I think [uri-templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) are an extremely interesting feature for REST based applications. But appart from //put your favorite language here// based implementations I don't see any support for it in HTML itself.

It seems support for it was intended for WebForms2.0 as described here: http://blog.welldesignedurls.org/2007/01/11/proposing-uri-templates-for-webforms-2/ and http://blog.whatwg.org/proposing-uri-templates-for-webforms-20 but according to the [WebForms2.0 page](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-forms/current-work/) it got replaced by [HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/) which doesn't mention templates as far as I can tell.

So my questions are: Is there support of URI-Templates in HTML?
If not is there: Is anything like this planned?
Or is there something like an emerging standard, something everybody does and which might end up being a standard at some time in the future?

Comment: Are you looking for a workaround or a specific documentation of that feature if it exists?

Comment: I'd prefer specific documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is really awesome, but I couldn't find any specific documentation for it. I guess that there can be a workaround with some JavaScript with an onsubmit event to build a new URI and then submit.

Actually there is a list with [uri-template implementations](http://code.google.com/p/uri-templates/wiki/Implementations). For HTML/Browserside support [the JavaScript version](https://github.com/fxa/uritemplate-js) seems to be most useful.